# HP ML350 G5 E200i Smart Array not always show at POST

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have a new used ML350 server and there is something strange with the Smart Array Controller, sometimes it show at POST (message with F8 possibility to configure) and sometimes not. Can't do any firmware update when not showed, and the last time I started the firmware has hanged. I removed the cache battery, no change.

**Edit :**

The server is an HP ProLiant ML350 G5 with SmartArray E200i onboard, do someone have experienced difficulty with this controller that *sometimes* doesn't appear in POST (normally there is a message saying Press F8 to configure...) and found a solution to fix it? When it is not detected, I can't use drives connected to it and also can't upgrade the SmartArray firmware.

Thank you.

Comment: Your post is lacking some serious detail. For example, array controller model number, pice/pcix/on board, etc. also, you're missing a question! What do you want to know?

Comment: Have you used the HP diagnostics to check hardware?  Have you obtained the HP Support Pack and checked for updates?

Comment: I'll try to get a diagnostic tool, the F10 button get into some tool but only for CPU and memory. For the HP support, this is a used server so no more support or warranty available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally installed a new RAID Controller (P400) and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You can download bootable CDs from the HP website (look on the 'downloads' page for your server model) that will allow you to run diagnostics tools as well as update the firmware on all devices in your server.  Start by running the array diagnostics utility and see what it reports.